# Google Sheets SUMIF Text Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Ok so, I will arleady say that im not that good with excel and even worse on google sheets.
I would like to know if there is a formula that checks for the name of someone and then sums the points said person got to his total. Thank you very much!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4M8Dlao8yFHJulNDff-i2jZJeVGGY_gejbAfzWdhFo/edit?usp=sharing is the link if you want to check it out.

Comment: Best to [edit] your question with a copy of your sheet, or at least some sample data. Otherwise it's pretty hard to help

Comment: @BigBen Done, hope you can help me now

Comment: Basically, you see all the players, I need a formula that check if the player has partecipated in the tournament and if he did than it sums the points said player got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want **Punti tot.** (`R:R`) column to have the sum of all **TA Brawl** (column `C:C`), **Notte** (`L:L`) and **50 Shades** (`H:H`; in this case any of the two players should be checked, right?) for every player.

You can use put this in `R2` (do not forget to remove everything below `R2`):

```
={
  "Punti tot.";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      P3:P = ""; ;
          SUMIF(A3:A; P3:P; C3:C)
        + SUMIF(E3:E; P3:P; H3:H)
        + SUMIF(F3:F; P3:P; H3:H)
        + SUMIF(J3:J; P3:P; L3:L)
    )
  )
}
```

[image]

---

**Update:** here is another solution using `QUERY` which is also sorts players by total points:

```
=QUERY(
  {
    FILTER({A3:A\ C3:C}; A3:A <> "");
    FILTER({E3:E\ H3:H}; E3:E <> "");
    FILTER({F3:F\ H3:H}; F3:F <> "");
    FILTER({J3:J\ L3:L}; J3:J <> "")
  };
  "
    select Col1, SUM(Col2)
    group by Col1
    order by SUM(Col2) desc,
             Col1
    label Col1 'Player',
          SUM(Col2) 'Punti tot.'
  ";
  -1
)
```

[image]

And you might want to use this in `O2` for ranking:

```
={
  "Posizioni Finali";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    RANK(
      FILTER(Q3:Q; Q3:Q <> "");
      FILTER(Q3:Q; Q3:Q <> "")
    )
  )
}
```

This way same amount of points gives players the same place. Otherwise **hysen** would get 9th place and **Imurshh** would be 10th just because **h** goes before **i**.

[image]

Comment: Edited this: added `IF` checking for empty cells.

Comment: I want a formula that checks if player X has played in any of those tournaments (those are tourneys btw) and if so sums the amount of points he got and outputs it in the Punti Tot. section
It needs to have lots of imputs but 1 output

Comment: Every column after you find "Pozioni", so basically the 3rd column of every set, the column changes name based on the tourneys name but ye 3rd column

Comment: I think its correct, yes both players should be checked.
If a player that shows up in the first tourney but not in the second tourney and in the first he gets idk like 20 points and ofc in the second none cuz he didnt participate, the total is still 20, that's an example, if the formula does this than it should be perfect

Comment: It does that. If the player is not in a tourney - no points for him from that tourney.

Comment: ok, i tried, there is 1 part missing but i guess i can fix it by hand and its probably a bit too difficult to do it with a formula

Comment: @UnLegitCombos do you need to get a list of all the player names? Or do you want to also sort them based on those total points? All this could be done, I think

Comment: I arleady fixed, if you go check i wanted it to arleady have all the players sorted and printed in the players column but i ended up doing it by hand

Comment: oh and another thing, i just remembered, the 2v2 tournament, the one were you find 2 players as entrants, does it give 30 points to each one or does it divide between them

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I can do my italian power rankings for brawlhalla without using a calculator, yay!

Comment: Oh wait, i tried using query instead, the thing is that with query it gives me more players than using the other solution, idk why tbh

Comment: @UnLegitCombos what is the other solution? Query just gives you all the unique player names.

Comment: using arrayformula i needed to get all players and then elimanate duplicates, and it would give me like 180 something, but with query its a bit more, how could it be possible?

Comment: share this arrayformula of yours, I'll take a look

Comment: its the one u sent me :/

Comment: The first one? It just sums points for the users which were already in column `P:P`. It did not populate user list. I don't think it matters anymore, i was just curious. Glad to help. Take care!